# Using IEnumerator to iterate through a list

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have a list of employee instances, `employeeList`. I can iterate through them, like this:

```
IEnumerator enumerator = employeeList.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.Write(enumerator.Current + " ");
}
```

I have three questions:

1. I have a general idea about how enumerators work, just like iterators in C++. But I don't understand the `MoveNext()` method (like `itr ++` in C++), because the method first checks the condition (whether it is in the last element). Let's say we use `enumerator.Current` to access the first element: I think it actually has already "moved" to the next element in the list, as `MoveNext()` has been called. So shouldn't the object that `Current` points to actually be the second element in the list?
2. I think it would make sense that we can access the current element when using `enumerator.Current`. For example, we should be able to use `enumerator.Current.name`, just like we can use `(*itr).name` or `itr=>name` in C++. However, C# looks like it doesn't implement this kind of functionality. So what's the point of using `enumerator.Current`?
3. This question is not related to IEnumerator. I just saw some code like this:
   `IEnumerable<int> result = GetData() ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>;`
   As a beginner in C#, I only know the `&&` and `||` operators. What is `??`?

Comment: 3 is the null-coalescing operator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Why don't you use `foreach`? Why are you trying to use the underlying implementation?

Comment: A side-note, if you're obtaining the `IEnumerator` object manually (and not through `foreach`), you need to dispose it when you're done enumerating, typically by wrapping the whole thing in a `using` block. `using (IEnumerator enumerator = ...) { while (...) { } }`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Read [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3207y01(v=vs.110).aspx): *"After an enumerator is created, the enumerator is positioned **before the first** element in the collection, and the first call to `MoveNext` **advances the enumerator to the first element** of the collection"*

The problem with your code is that you assign the enumerator to a non-generic enumerator variable. That works because the generic `IEnumerator<T>` interface inherits from the non-generic. But that's also the reason why you can't use properties of the `Employee`-class since the type is `Object`. You have to cast `enumerator.Current` to the correct type first.

Therefore it's better to use the generic version (and dipose it properly with `using`):

```
using(IEnumerator<Employee> empEnumerator = employeeList.GetEnumerator())
{
    while(empEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // now empEnumerator.Current is the Employee instance without casting
        Employee emp = empEnumerator.Current;
        string empName = emp.Name;  // ...
    }
}
```

You can also use `var` which works like a placeholder for the real type in C#:

```
using(var empEnumerator = employeeList.GetEnumerator())
{ ... }
```

If all you need is to enumerate the whole collection a `foreach` is more comfortable:

```
foreach(Employee emp in employeeList)
{
     Console.WriteLine(emp.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Initially, the enumerator is positioned *before* the first element (since an enumerable might be empty). Thus, the first invocation of `MoveNext` moves it to the first element (or returns false, if the enumerable is empty).
2. You are using the old, non-generic version of `IEnumerator`, where `Current` returns an `object`. You can cast the object to the concrete type and invoke `.name`, or, even better, use a type for `employeeList` which returns a strongly typed `IEnumerator<Employee>` (such as `List<Employee>`).
3. This is the [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

PS: In the future, please create one SO question per question. 1+2 can be seen as related, but 3 definitely isn't.

PPS: If you just want a space-separated list of employee names, you don't need an explicit loop at all:

```
var names = String.Join(" ", employeeList.Select(e => e.name));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `IEnumerable` just this way:

```
foreach (var e in employeeList)
{
  Console.Write(e + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[IEnumerable Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Exposes an enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a non-generic collection.

```
foreach (var employee in employeeList)
{
    // do your stuff  here, you have full employee object
   Console.WriteLine(employee.FirstName); 
}
```

[c# null coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

The `??` operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

Comment: -1,                                                             again, for not using quote blocks to indicate what content is copied from your source.